# App logs in with previously entered credentials (React Native with firebase)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm working on a messaging application, wherein users can register/login to talk to other users.
Upon successful login, the user must be able to see all the registered users excluding themselves.  When I try to login with any account, I'm logged in with previously entered credentials.
I'm using React Native with expo. When I run the application for the first time and try logging in(say signing in as account A), it is somehow authenticated and I'm able to see all the registered users including **myself**, i.e A.
Further, when I sign out and try logging in with some other account(say account B), I'm logged in with account A's details, and all the registered users except (account A) are displayed.
Similarly, again if I sign out and try signing in with any other account (say account C or A), I'm logged in with account B's details and not C's or A's.
Attaching a few images for clarity:

1)When I log in for the first time( email:newuser@gmail.com, password:123456)
Result: Authenticated but all the users including self is displayed on the logged-in screen.
[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d00JD.jpg)

2)Signed out and logged in as a different user( email:test3@gmail.com, password:test123)
Result: Authenticated with previously entered credentials i.e logged in with email:newuser@gmail.com, password:123456).
[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJRh7.jpg)

3)Signed out and again logged in with same credentials as the previous one( email:test3@gmail.com, password:test123)
Result: Authenticated with previously entered credentials i.e logged in with email:test3@gmail.com, password:test123.
[Check screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhLiz.jpg)

**Login.js**

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, TextInput, Image, ImageBackground, ScrollView, AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import firebaseSvc from '../config/firebaseSDK'


export default class Login extends Component {

static navigationOptions = {
  title: 'Login',
};
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    name: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    user_Data: '',
    uid: '',
    username: '',
    uemail: ''
  };
}


onPressLogin = () => {
  var user = {

    email: this.state.email,
    password: this.state.password,
    //avatar: this.state.avatar,
  }


  const response = firebaseSvc.login(
    user,
    this.loginSuccess,
    this.loginFailed,
  )


  this.Data_match()



}

Data_match = () => {
  firebaseSvc.loginData().then((solve) => {
    this.setState({ user_Data: solve })
  }).then(() => {
    let x = this.state.user_Data
    this.setState({
      uid: x.uid,
      username: x.displayName,
      uemail: x.email
    })

  }).catch((fail) => {
    console.log('not getting data.....')
  })
}

loginSuccess = () => {



  this.props.navigation.navigate('Users', {
    name: this.state.name,
    email: this.state.email,
    avatar: this.state.avatar,
    uid: this.state.uid,
    username: this.state.username,
    uemail: this.state.uemail
  })


   console.log(
     'uid=> '+this.state.uid+
     '  username=> '+this.state.username+
     '  useremail=> '+this.state.uemail
   )

}
loginFailed = () => {
  console.log('login failed ***');
  alert('Login failed.');
}
onChangeTextEmail = email => this.setState({ email:email });
onChangeTextPassword = password => this.setState({ password:password });

render() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground style={styles.loginbox}  >
        <ScrollView>
          <View style={styles.padding_btm}>
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
              keyboardType='email-address'
              placeholder='Email or Mobile Num'
              onChangeText={this.onChangeTextEmail}
              value={this.state.email}
            />
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
              placeholder='Password'
              secureTextEntry
              onChangeText={this.onChangeTextPassword}
              value={this.state.password}
            />

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={this.onPressLogin}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>LOGIN</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={() => 
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Signup")}>
              <Text style={styles.buttonText}>CREATE ACCOUNT NOW</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  )
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})
```

**firebaseSDK.js**

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import 'firebase/firestore'


const config = {
  apiKey: 'XXX',
  authDomain: 'XXX',
  databaseURL: 'XXX',
  projectId: 'XXX',
  storageBucket: 'XXX',
  messagingSenderId: 'XXX'
}
class FirebaseSvc {
  constructor(props) {

    if (!firebase.apps.length) {
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    } else {
      console.log("firebase apps already running...")
    }
  }

  authData=(email)=>{
    firebase
    .database()
    .ref('users')
    .orderByChild('emailAddress')
    .equalTo(email)
    .once('value', snap => console.log('this is authantcation data==> '+snap.val()))
  }

  login (user, success_callback, failed_callback) {
    console.log("RECEVING SIDE:"+user.email+" "+user.password)

    const output =  firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(user.email,
    user.password).then(success_callback, failed_callback)


  }

  loginData=()=>{
          return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
            firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
              if (user) {
                //console.log("user: ", user);
                resolve(user)
                // User is signed in.
              } else {
                // No user is signed in.
            } 
      }) 
    }) 
  }

  observeAuth = () =>{
    console.log("OBSERVING LOGOUT")
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(this.onAuthStateChanged);
  }
  onAuthStateChanged = user => {
    if (!user) {
      try {
        this.login(user);
      } catch ({ message }) {
        console.log("Failed:" + message)
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Reusing auth...");
    }
  }

  createAccount = async (user) => {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    firebase.auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then(function(pass){
        var userf = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        userf.updateProfile({ displayName: user.name})
        .then(function() {
           firebase.firestore().collection("fb_user").doc(pass.user.uid).set({
            uid: pass.user.uid,
            email: pass.user.email,
            name:user.name,
            emailVerified:pass.user.emailVerified
        })
        .then(function() {
            console.log("Document successfully written!");
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
        });  
          alert("User " + user.name + " was created successfully. Please login.")
        }, function(error) {
          console.warn("Error update displayName.");
        });
      }, function(error) {
        console.error("got error:" + typeof(error) + " string:" + error.message);
        alert("Create account failed. Error: "+error.message);
      })
    })
  }  



  onLogout = user => {
     firebase.auth().signOut().then(() =>{

      console.log("Sign-out successful.");

    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log("An error occured while signing out:"+error);
    });

  }
 . // miscellaneous code 
 .
 .
  get uid() {
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
  }

  get timestamp() {
    return firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP;
  }



}

const firebaseSvc = new FirebaseSvc();
export default firebaseSvc;
```

I highly doubt if this issue is concerned with the "setState" being an async function and maybe I'm triggering the login event at the wrong place. Yet, I'm unclear and not sure of the root cause.
Any help or suggestions would be highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part of code is causing the error:-

```
 const response = firebaseSvc.login(
user,
this.loginSuccess,
this.loginFailed,
 )
this.Data_match()
```

May be here your loginSuccess() is running before Data_match(), so it navigates with the previous state of the variable because state are updating in Data_match().
Hence, pass, this.Data_match() instead of loginSuccess in the firebaseSvc.login callback.
Add, navigation logic in Data_match().

```
const response = firebaseSvc.login(
    user,
    //this.loginSuccess,
    this.Data_match(),
    this.loginFailed,
     )
    //this.Data_match()
)

Data_match = () => {
    firebaseSvc.loginData().then((solve) => {
      this.setState({ user_Data: solve })
    }).then(() => {
      let x = this.state.user_Data
      this.setState({
        uid: x.uid,
        username: x.displayName,
        uemail: x.email
      })

      this.props.navigation.push('Users', {
        name: this.state.name,
        email: this.state.email,
        avatar: this.state.avatar,
        uid: this.state.uid,
        username: this.state.username,
        uemail: this.state.uemail
      })


       console.log(
         'uid=> '+this.state.uid+
         '  username=> '+this.state.username+
         '  useremail=> '+this.state.uemail
       )

    }).catch((fail) => {
      console.log('not getting data..............................................')
    })
  }
```

This implies that the loginSuccess function is now obsolete.

Try checking it.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Tried as suggested. The problem still persists.

Comment: try to navigate in callBack of Data_match().

Comment: Yes, the loginSuccess was fired before Data_match(), and thus, it was navigating with previous state. Made changes as said. Works perfectly now.